# Transactionscope with 2 different Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, transactionscope

I am trying to implement `TransactionScope` for the following  scenario

- Open Transaction scope and perform 2 Db insertion using EF approach
- Get the LAST INSERT ID for the 2
- Open a new MySQL Transaction here to perform some local SQL queries [I am getting error here  "Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported."]

If all queries on different Db executed then save the `TransactionScope` else reject

The code I am using is like

```
bool _noError = false;
bool can_commit_transaction = false;
bool can_executeSQL = false;

int server_masterId = 0;
int server_sessionId = 0;

// Define a transaction scope for the operations.            
EduAdminEntities transactional_context = new EduAdminEntities();

using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        #region Entity Framework SQL Execution
        schoolmaster master = new schoolmaster { Name = "test name", Address = "address" };                    

        session _session = new session();
        _session.Session = "session 1";
        _session.IsActive = 1;
        master.sessions.Add(_session);

        transactional_context.AddToschoolmasters(master);
        #endregion

        #region Different Db SQL Execution using SQL Command
        //read server last insert ids and if its > 0 execute SQl queries on a different Db using these 2 ids
        server_masterId = master.Id;
        server_sessionId = _session.Id;

        if (server_masterId > 0 && server_sessionId > 0)
        {
            can_executeSQL = true;
        }                  

        if (can_executeSQL)
        {
            MySqlTransaction pageTransaction = null;
            string connection_string = string.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Database={2};User={3};Password={4};", _Server, _Port, _Database, _User, _Password);
            Connection dbConnection = new Connection(connection_string);
            Connection.MyConnection.Open();

            pageTransaction = Connection.MyConnection.BeginTransaction();
            MySqlCommand pageCommand = new MySqlCommand("", Connection.MyConnection, pageTransaction);

            try
            {
                 string _sql = "";
                 #region Schoolmaster configuration
                 pageCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                 _sql = "insert into schoolmaster(Id,Name,Address)values(@Id,@Name,@Address)";
                 pageCommand.CommandText = _sql;
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", server_masterId);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", master.Name);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", master.Address);
                 pageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 pageCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                 _sql = "UPDATE session SET IsActive=0 WHERE IsActive=1 AND  SchoolId= @SchoolId";
                 pageCommand.CommandText = _sql;
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolId", server_masterId);

                 pageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 //-----------------------------
                 pageCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                 _sql = "insert into session(Id,SchoolId,Session,IsActive,Description)values(@Id,@SchoolId,@Session,@IsActive,@Description)";
                 pageCommand.CommandText = _sql;
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", server_sessionId);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolId", server_masterId);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Session", _session.Session);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", _session.IsActive);
                 pageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", _session.Description);

                 pageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 #endregion

                 _noError = true;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 _noError = false;
             }
             finally
             {
                 if (_noError)
                 {
                      pageTransaction.Commit();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     pageTransaction.Rollback();
                 }

                 if (Connection.MyConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                     Connection.MyConnection.Close();
             }
         }
         #endregion

         transactional_context.SaveChanges(false);
         can_commit_transaction = true;
     }
     catch
     {
     }
}

if (can_commit_transaction)
{   
    transactional_context.AcceptAllChanges();
}

// Dispose the object context.
transactional_context.Dispose();
```

How can I avoid the error

> Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s Here i am having issues while Opening connection. I agrees that AddwithValue() might have some drawbacks , but i in my case i am not been able to open connection at all

Comment: As the error clearly says: if you're in the middle of a transaction - you cannot connect to another database. You need to rearchitect your code to take that into account.